# Inner join of two tables [UPDATED]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, inner-join

tbl teacher

```
lrn
fname
lname
email
image
schedule
```

tbl user

```
lrn
fname
lname
email
image
account-type
```

$id=$_SESSION['id'];

$get_record_sched = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT schedule FROM teacher INNER JOIN users ON teacher.lrn = users.lrn WHERE teacher.lrn = '$id' ");

I want to echo the exact schedule based on the id of the logged in account. But with this, query, there's no output...

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires the connection as the parameter. Do you also fetch the results from this query?

Comment: yes sir i did...i just can get the specific schedule

Comment: Neither of your tables seem to contain ID column. Also, why joining at all if the SCHEDULE column is already present in the TEACHER table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: here's my new query, i can now echo all the schedule but not the exact schedule for id 

$get_record_sched = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT schedule FROM teacher INNER JOIN users ON teacher.lrn = users.lrn WHERE teacher.lrn = users.lrn");

Comment: @anne you repeat the joining condition in the WHERE part which is not neccessary. Instead, you probably want to place the id provided by the user user there in form of a parameter: WHERE users.lrn = $idFromUser

Answer (score 1):

You said you have `$id` from the session. Assuming that column `lrn` is the ID, then

```
Select t.schedule
From teacher t
Where t.lrn = $id
```

No need to join the table with the user table.

Note that parameter binding is advised.

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("Select t.schedule From teacher t Where t.lrn = ?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $id);
```

Comment: This answer breaks it down to the point! Further more prepared statement is used which generally should be common practice.

Answer (score 0):

In you where condition was wrong.They don't have any param to validate condition.so change like this

```
"SELECT schedule FROM teacher INNER JOIN users  ON teacher.id = users.id WHERE 1  "
```

**OR**

use same where condition with join

```
"SELECT schedule FROM teacher INNER JOIN users  ON teacher.id = users.id AND teacher.schedule = users.id   WHERE 1  "
```

**OR**

if You have logged used id in session like

```
$id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

"SELECT schedule FROM teacher INNER JOIN users ON teacher.id = users.id WHERE teacher.schedule='$id' "
```

Comment: you are right .if i formatted my code .They answer was go very log.Its not necessary now

Comment: the last code is not workin, i have $id=$_SESSION['id']; and i tried what you said, but it's still not showing the exact schedule

Comment: are you call `session_start()` on before `$id=$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
   $id = $_SESSION["id"];

Comment: ok do one thing `echo "SELECT schedule FROM teacher INNER JOIN users ON teacher.id = users.id WHERE teacher.schedule='$id' "; exit();` copy paste to  with phpmyadmin.And tell if have any error

Comment: i got the exact account when i logged in but i can't echo the exact schedule for that account and the schedule column is on table teacher

Comment: can you post the two table screen shot .And tell one example matching result?

Comment: the two table have the same data except the schedule and account_type, i want want to echo the exact schedule when i logged in the account.